# restapi receive complex json

Tags: c#, angular, rest

I am stuck.
I I pass a simple json object it works fine.  But I i make it a little more complex.  In this case a fileInfo object inside my message object I am having trouble.
File info is null when received.  I know I must be overlooking something simple.
Here is an example of a json object I am passing.

thanks in advance.

[image]

```
public class ContactUsInformation
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public IList<AttachmentInfo> fileInfo{ get; set; }
    //public AttachmentInfo[] fileInfo { get; set; }
    /*public string[] fileName { get; set; }
    public string[] fileType{ get; set; }
    public string[] fileValue { get; set; }*/
}
public class AttachmentInfo{
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string fileType { get; set; }
    public string fileValue { get; set; }
}
```

public IEnumerable Contact([FromBody]ContactUsInformation[] contactUsInformation)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On the JavaScript side I see **fileInfo** with a string value.  Is this correct?
- In JavaScript, are you setting fileInfo using **JSON.stringify** ?  If so just use the object, then it will serialize properly (hopefully)

Comment: never noticed the double quotes.  I will check if that is the problem.